# Knn graph differences: Mathematica and sklearn

Tags: graphs-and-networks, python

I have this data: [Data file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wAWwp_1sxDNKqe2cNIuDCx2H4ScdKFT5/view?usp=sharing)

I made 8-NN graph as follows:

```
data20 = Import["~/Downloads/data_20.mat"];
ndata20 = Table[Flatten[data20[[i]]], {i, Length[data20]}];
tndata20 = Transpose[ndata20];
gp = NearestNeighborGraph[tndata20, 8, 
   DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance, DirectedEdges -> False];
adj = AdjacencyMatrix[gp];
```

This gives a symmetric adjacency matrix:

```
adj == Transpose[adj]
True
```

This is what I did in python:

```
import scipy.io
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('~/Downloads/data_20.mat')
mat2 =[]
for i in range(60000):
    mat2.append(mat['foo'][i])
mat2 = np.array(mat2)
mat22 = mat2.reshape(60000,784)
mat22T = mat22.T
from sklearn.neighbors import kneighbors_graph
A = kneighbors_graph(mat22T, 8, mode='connectivity')
aa = A.toarray()
```

This gives an antisymmetric matrix:

```
(aa==aa.T).all()
False
```

Sklearn and Mathematica aren't using the same algorithm for k-nn graph construction. How can I get the same result in python and vice-versa?

EDITS: Following the comments by @Szabolcs, I made some edits.

Naively, this is how I think it should work:

1. First calculate distances between all the nodes. To calculate the distance you should choose a distance metric. In my case that would be the Euclidean metric. This gives a Distance matrix.
2. If I want to make an 8-NN graph then I would find 8 closet neighbors to the node using the distance matrix. Using this idea, I can find neighbors for all the nodes. This gives a graph.
3. If the graph is undirected then the graph representation (adjacency matrix) would be symmetric because if node i is connected to node j then node j is also connected to node i. Basically, the connection is bi-directional.

Here's an example:

**Mathematica:**

```
dat = {{-1, -1}, {-2, -1}, {-3, -2}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}};
gp11 = NearestNeighborGraph[dat, 2, Method -> "KDtree", 
  DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance, DirectedEdges -> False ]
adj1 = AdjacencyMatrix[gp11];
adj1 == Transpose[adj1]
True
```

**Python with sklearn:**

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
kdt1 = KDTree(X, metric='euclidean')
A11 = kneighbors_graph(kdt1, 2, mode='connectivity')
a11 = A11.toarray()
(a11==a11.T).all()
True
```

However, the same approach does not work for my dataset.
Thanks a lot for reading my question.

Comment: That's not Python, it's sklearn to be accurate. There are many different Python packages. Can you change the title and the description? Also, can you give a plain English description of what `kneighbors_graph` does in sklearn?  Euclidean distance is obviously symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sklearn` makes a directed knn graph.

In the case of mathematica:

```
adj = NearestNeighborGraph[pts, 2, DirectedEdges -> True]
mat = AdjacencyMatrix[adj]
mat == Transpose[mat]
False

adj1 = NearestNeighborGraph[pts, 2, DirectedEdges -> False]
mat1 = AdjacencyMatrix[adj1]
mat1 == Transpose[mat1]
True
```

In the case of `sklearn`, using the same data as @Szabolcs':

```
xt=np.array([[0.753217, 
  0.0439285], [-0.827553, -0.244174], [0.0875135, -0.0413367], 
[-0.509302, 0.519792], [-0.0819656, 
  0.769458], [0.167709, -0.472054], [0.83912, -0.15233], [0.974581, 
  0.175885], [0.392318, 0.503732], [-0.196902, 0.265483]]);
adj = kneighbors_graph(xt, 2,metric='euclidean', mode='connectivity')
adj11 = adj.toarray()
(adj11==adj11.T).all()
False
```

How can I force `sklearn` to produce an undirected graph?
Just do this:

```
adj11 = adj11 + adj11.T
adj11[adj11 > 1] = 1
```

This `adj11` is equal to `mat1`

Answer (score 4):

I did not look at sklearn, but I wanted to note that by default, `NearestNeighborGraph` creates an undirected graph. This means that the adjacency matrix is symmetric. We can use `DirectedEdges -> True` to get a directed graph:

```
SeedRandom[1234];
pts = RandomPoint[Disk[], 10];

NearestNeighborGraph[pts, 2, DirectedEdges -> True]
```

[image]

Notice that not all connections are reciprocal. This is because if point B is A's closest neighbour, that does not mean that A is also B's closest neighbour.

While I did not try sklearn, perhaps this is the source of the difference. You can test it on a small example.